# How to pass javascript array of dictionary to flask

Tags: javascript, python, http, flask, python-requests

I have an `array of dictionaries` in `javascript` that I want to send as payload to a `POST` request to flask.

However, the array always gets sent empty.

Javascript:

```js
{% for department in departments %}
        var department_id = "{{ department.id }}"
        var cardgroup = $("#cardgroups_{{ department.id }}").val();
        var doorgroup = $("#doorgroups_{{ department.id }}").val();

        data.push({
            department_id: department_id,
            cardgroup_id: cardgroup,
            doorgroup_id: doorgroup
        });
{% endfor %}

$.post("data/save-office/"+office, data={data: data}, function (data) {
        if (data['error']) {
            alert(data['error']);
        }
        else
            if (data['success']) {
                load_table();
            }
        });
```

python:

```py
@app.post('/data/save-office/<office>')
def save_office(office):
    departments = request.args.getlist('data[]').  # departments = []
```

I tried to change `departments` to `request.args.getlist('data')` but it returned the same thing.

I also tried to use AJAX instead but it was basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on only provide an answer to your original question, you can pass an array to flask as the body of a POST request, Flask automatically handles JSON to dict conversion as-is.
Consider this code block as an example of how to send that data:

```js
var my_json_array = [{
  "key": "val"
}, {
  "key": "val"
}]

async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', .
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: data 
  });
  return response.json();
}

postData('http://localhost:5000/test', my_json_array)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Note: I want to give credit to MDN for the fetch API sample I used on this post, visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch to know more about this new JavaScript API feature